# How to select titles that are like the first n characters of a string?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example

There are titles of some animes:

```
|_title_|
|My hero Academia|
|My hero Academia Season 2|
|My hero Academia Season 3|
|My hero Academia Season 4|
```

And I'd like to select those titles, that contain the first 10 character of the first record, so "My Hero Academia" in this example

It's important that it must be the first N characters, like 10,15,20. So `SELECT title FROM tablename WHERE title LIKE "%My hero Academia%"` is not the solution I'm looking for.

Also: this is just an example,there are many other titles too, and I don't always know what the first 10 characters are. So I also can't simply put the first 10 characters of "My hero academia" in the `WHERE title LIKE` clause.

I mean something like this:

```
SELECT title FROM table_name
WHERE title LIKE the first 10 characters of a given string
```

Is there a way to do that with SQL?

Comment: can you  provide more clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for filter a string for  a partial fixed  value you can use like operator  `like 'yourstring%'` eg:

```
    SELECT title 
    FROM your_table  
    WHERE title LIKE 'thefirst10%'
```

or use a string fuction like substr or left

```
    SELECT title 
    FROM your_table  
    WHERE left(title,10) = 'thefirst10'  

    SELECT title 
    FROM your_table  
    WHERE substr(title,1,10) = 'thefirst10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the 10 characters in like this:

```
WHERE title LIKE 'aaaaaaaaaa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(title, 1, n) = 'aaaaaaaaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE title like "data structure%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE title LIKE '%'  + substring('AAA' , 0 ,2)
```

First parameter of substring function represent of your string ,second start index and third end index.You can change end index as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the wildcard character (%):

```
SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE title LIKE "1234567890%"
```

Answer (score 0):

this could help you it qorks for my postgray11. ithink it will hwlp for your mysql

```
select * from t1 where title LIKE CONCAT((select * from t1 LIMIT 1),'%');
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=02a894d6582ff1c6946d74e43b886f1b)